# Terraform .id explanation

Tags: terraform

I'm new to Terraform and am confused by the `id` attribute returned by resources.

Given:

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "aas_mng_subnet" {
  name                 = "${var.prefix}-${var.env_type}-subnet-${var.site_octet}.50.x"
  virtual_network_name = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.main.name}"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.prefix}-${var.env_type}"
}
```

and

```
subnet_id = "${data.azurerm_subnet.aas_mng_subnet.id}"
```

What will the `subnet_id` value be? 
I mean in general - not specific to this example.
What is the value of the `.id` attribute in every place it appears?

The [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#attributes-of-other-resources) attempts to explain this but I'm not sure I understand it still:

> Attributes of a data source
>
> The syntax is data.TYPE.NAME.ATTRIBUTE.
>   For example. `${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}` will interpolate the `id`
>   attribute from the `aws_ami` data source named `ubuntu`. If the data
>   source has a count attribute set, you can access individual attributes
>   with a zero-based index, such as
>   `${data.aws_subnet.example.0.cidr_block}`. You can also use the splat
>   syntax to get a list of all the attributes:
>   `${data.aws_subnet.example.*.cidr_block}`.

I'll be grateful if someone can explain it to me with other words and\or examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the subnet ID returned by Azure so should look something like `/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/subnet-test/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnetname/subnets/subnet1`.

Other resources and other providers will return other things for the ID but in general the principle is that the ID for a resource is something that is unique for the provider (so the account and anything else that might differentiate it such as the region).

I don't know the Azure provider that well but for example the [`aws_instance` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html) will return an ID that is the instance ID which looks something like `i-abcdef1234567890` and the [`aws_lb` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb.html) that creates Application/Network Load Balancers has an ID that is the [ARN (Amazon Resource Name)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) and looks something like `arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:$REGION_NAME:$ACCOUNT_NUMBER:loadbalancer/app/my-example-alb/abcdef1234567890`.

Comment: So is it like an Object reference\address\hash code? Some ID of the object.

Comment: Yep, exactly that. Something that Terraform can refer to internally but doesn't necessarily have to be known/used directly in the config. So if you create a resource A and another resource B needs to know resource A's unique identifier so it can use it in some way (such as placing the VM in the appropriate subnet) then you can just pass it by interpolating the `id` attribute from the resource (or data source if you are looking it up rather than creating it in this Terraform action).

Comment: Terraform today treats the name `id` as a bit special for some historical reasons, but from a user perspective (as opposed to a provider developer perspective) it's just like any other attribute: it means whatever the provider decides that it means. Conventionally it's where the provider will save the primary identifier for the object as recorded in the remote system. There is no general definition of it that applies to all resource types, since it's a resource-type-specific thing.